# Stop never-ending popup alerts in FireFox

Tags: firefox, javascript

It is possible for javascript to get stuck in a loop of opening up alerts. For example:

```
for(var i=0;;i++)
    alert('This will never stop');
```

Is there a way to gracefully stop this in firefox, without having to kill the whole process?

Comment: This isn't a satisfactory general-purpose solution, but with Greasmonkey (or maybe Ubiquity or Jetpack) you could overwrite window.alert with a function that calls window.confirm and optionally throw()s an error, stopping all script execution, or toggles a flag to stop alerts. That might be useful if a site you keep going back to presents this behavior.

Comment: In Opera, each dialog has a checkbox saying "Stop executing scripts on this page", which when checked will solve the problem. Guess they should put it in firefox too.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps the 'NoScript' plugin could help. Ban the site and the script won't be executed at all

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow question reference: 
[How do you stop an infinite loop in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905322/how-do-you-stop-an-infinite-loop-in-javascript)

A critical difference in your loop is the pop-up (user interaction) that prevents the "slow-script" detection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're quick enough with it, click "Ok" then hit **F5**. You may have to confirm one or two more popups, but the page will reload and you'll be saved.

Comment: Page reload is useless if the rogue JS script runs when loading the page (a case I had).
But you inspired me to do [Ctrl+] Return and Ctrl+W in a quick sequence and finally I got rid of the page... (Ctrl+Return works as Return but having this key down helps for speed hit Ctrl+W!)
So +1 for you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I usually have the Javascript popup in focus so that I can just hit Enter to get rid of it.  Then, I position my mouse cursor just above the Close Tab button.  I then begin a race where I hit Enter to close the popup and immediately click the Close Tab button before it has a chance to create another popup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AlertStopper (https://addons.mozilla.org/af/firefox/addon/13530/) myself.